# When FIrebase is updated and onSnapshot updates the state, my screen follows the changed item, always scrolling to it

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Not sure how to sum this in a title so I'm sorry if my title is not as good as it needs to be.

I am working on a restaurant menu using React and Firebase.
I managed to create logic for manual reordering of documents in a collection.
Items state is updated via onSnapshot everytime Firebase data is changed and that update moves array items up and down but one thing bothers me. Whenever I change the order and onSnapshot updates my Items state my screen follows the item I moved. How can I prevent that behaviour or even better, add animation so it looks more like changing order.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TuQ3Um24rgUvfCKGhqUdGEZgrRvlLs3O/view

I am providing you with the video so you can exactly see what is going on, also I'm pasting my component that holds the reorder functionality

Thanks a lot.

```
import { collection, deleteDoc, doc, onSnapshot, orderBy, query, updateDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { db, storage } from '../firebase/config';
import { deleteObject, ref } from 'firebase/storage';
import ProductCard from './ProductCard';

export const EditContext = createContext()

function AdminItems({category, getAllAdminItems, removeAdminItem, filteredItems, isSearch}) {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    
    //  Fetching data from Firebase and storing all items in one array to handle search.
    //  useEffect works differently depending if filteredItems or Category is passed as a prop
    useEffect(() => {
        if (filteredItems) {
            setItems(filteredItems)
        } else if (category) {
            const q = query(collection (db, `${category.categoryPath}/items`), orderBy("orderTimestamp", "asc"));
            const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
                const snapshotData = [];
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    //  On each loop push current Item data to snapshotData array.
                    snapshotData.push(doc.data());
                    getAllAdminItems(doc.data())    //  Sends data to CategoryTabs.jsx to use in search bar
                });
                //  Put snapshotData array into Items state
                setItems(snapshotData)
                
            });
            return () => {
                unsubscribe();
            }
        } else {
            setItems([])
        }
            
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [category, filteredItems])




    //  Handles delete for item passed as an argument from ProductCard.jsx.
    const handleDelete = async (item) => {
        //  Confirmation before proceeding
        if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this product?")) {
            //  If item contains image, delete it
            if (item.filePath !== "") {
                const fileRef = ref(storage, item.filePath)
                deleteObject(fileRef).then(() => {
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error)
                });
            }
            //  Delete item
            removeAdminItem(item); //  Removes data from CategoryTabs.jsx to remove it from search bar
            await deleteDoc(doc(db, item.fullPath));

            //  Update lastedited timestamp to handle fetching from firestore or local storage.
            await updateDoc(doc(db, "/menu/additional"), {lastedited: Date.now()})
            
        }
    }

        //  Handles edit for item passed as an argument from ProductCard.jsx
    const handleEdit = async (itemObject, itemPath) => {
        try {
            //  Getting document ref from argument passed from ProductCard.jsx
            const docRef = doc(db, itemPath)
            //  Update the item and close the form
            await updateDoc(docRef, itemObject)

            //  Update lastedited timestamp to handle fetching from firestore or local storage.
            await updateDoc(doc(db, "/menu/additional"), {lastedited: Date.now()})

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }


    //  Handling manual item ordering with buttons UP and DOWN
    const handleReorder = async (item, direction) => {

        //  Calculating a middle timestamp value in order to put moving item inbetween two compared timestamps.
        const getMiddleValue = (num1, num2) => {
            const sum = num1 + num2
            const number = sum / 2
            return number
        }
        //  Getting moving item index and firebase ref
        const itemIndex = items.findIndex(doc => doc.id === item.id )
        const docRef = doc(db, items[itemIndex].fullPath)

        const itemsLength = items.length - 1

        //  If one item in array, do nothing.
        if (items.length <= 1) {
            return
        }

        //  Handling move UP
        if (direction === "up") {

            //  If moving item is first, don't move UP
            if (itemIndex === 0) {
                return
            }

            //  If moving item is second in array
            if (itemIndex === 1) {
                const prevOrder1 = items[1 - 1].orderTimestamp
                const middleValue = getMiddleValue(0, prevOrder1)
                //  Saving current scroll position to handle "scroll lock"
                try {
                    //  Updating moved item document's orderTimestamp
                    await updateDoc(docRef, {
                        orderTimestamp: middleValue,
                    })
                    //  Update lastedited timestamp to handle fetching from firestore or local storage.
                    await updateDoc(doc(db, "/menu/additional"), {lastedited: Date.now()})
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            }

            //  If moving item is neither first nor second in array
            if (itemIndex >= 2) {
                const prevOrder1 = items[itemIndex - 1].orderTimestamp
                const prevOrder2 = items[itemIndex - 2].orderTimestamp
                const middleValue = getMiddleValue(prevOrder1, prevOrder2)
                try {
                    //  Updating moved item document's orderTimestamp
                    await updateDoc(docRef, {
                        orderTimestamp: middleValue,
                    })
                    //  Update lastedited timestamp to handle fetching from firestore or local storage.
                    await updateDoc(doc(db, "/menu/additional"), {lastedited: Date.now()})
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            }

        //  Handling move DOWN
        } else if (direction === "down") {

            //  If moving item is last in the array
            if (itemIndex === itemsLength) {
                return
            }

            //  If moving item is second to last in the array
            if (itemIndex === itemsLength - 1) {
                const prevOrder1 = items[itemsLength].orderTimestamp
                const middleValue = prevOrder1 + 10
                try {
                    //  Updating moved item document's orderTimestamp
                    await updateDoc(docRef, {
                        orderTimestamp: middleValue,
                    })
                    //  Update lastedited timestamp to handle fetching from firestore or local storage.
                    await updateDoc(doc(db, "/menu/additional"), {lastedited: Date.now()})
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            }

            //  If moving item is neither last nor second to last in the array
            else {
                const prevOrder1 = items[itemIndex + 1].orderTimestamp
                const prevOrder2 = items[itemIndex + 2].orderTimestamp
                const middleValue = getMiddleValue(prevOrder1, prevOrder2)
                try {
                    //  Updating moved item document's orderTimestamp
                    await updateDoc(docRef, {
                        orderTimestamp: middleValue,
                    })
                    //  Update lastedited timestamp to handle fetching from firestore or local storage.
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <EditContext.Provider value={{
            handleEdit,
        }}>
        <div>
            {items?.map((item) => (
                <ProductCard item={item} key={item.id} handleDelete={handleDelete} isAdmin={true} handleReorder={handleReorder} isSearch={isSearch}/>
            ))}
        </div>
        </EditContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default AdminItems
```

I tried saving current scroll position before doing the change then after the change scrolling back to that position, that works okay but I'd like to know what's the reason my component works like showed in the video.

Also I tried to use react-spring but that animated the whole component, not each mapped item separately.

I am not sure what terms to use to search SO for the answer so I had to create a new question.